# Calculation of Riemann Curvature Tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

I am reading the book:  "Analysis and Algebra on Differentiable Manifolds: A Workbook for Students and Teachers" (P.M.Gadea, J.Munoz Masque) Problem 6.5.1. Page 252-253:

Find the Riemann curvature tensor of the Riemannian manifold $(U,g)$, where $U$ denotes the unit open disk of the plane $\mathbf{R}^2$ and $$g=\frac{1}{(1 - x^2 - y^2)}(dx^2 + dy^2)$$

The Solution is given as follows:
$$g^{-1}= \begin{pmatrix} 1-x^2 - y^2 & 0 \\\\ 0 & 1-x^2-y^2 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$x=x^1, y=x^2$$, the Christoffel symbols are:

$$\Gamma_{11}^{1} = \Gamma_{12}^{2}= \Gamma_{21}^{2}= - \Gamma_{22}^{1}= \frac{x}{1-x^2-y^2}$$

$$- \Gamma_{11}^{2}= \Gamma_{12}^{1}= \Gamma_{21}^{1}= \Gamma_{22}^{2}= \frac{y}{1-x^2-y^2}$$

Therefore, $$R \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right) = g \left( R(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y})\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \right)$$
$$= - \frac{2}{(1-x^2-y^2)^2}$$
The above is the full solution given in the book. Below is my computation:
But, I could not obtain the same result, instead I get the following:
$$R \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right) = R_{1212} = g_{1 \xi} R_{212}^{\xi}=g_{11}R_{212}^{1}$$

$$\frac{1}{(1-x^2-y^2)} \left[ \partial_{x} \left( \frac{-x}{1-x^2-y^2} \right) - \partial_{y} \left( \frac{y}{1-x^2-y^2} \right) + \Gamma_{11}^{1} \Gamma_{22}^{1} + \Gamma_{12}^{1} \Gamma_{22}^{2} - \Gamma_{21}^{1}\Gamma_{12}^{1} - \Gamma_{22}^{1} \Gamma_{12}^{2}\right]$$
which gives after some computations the following with two extra terms:
$$\frac{-2}{(1-x^2-y^2)^2} + \frac{-2x^2}{(1-x^2-y^2)^3} + \frac{-2y^2}{(1-x^2-y^2)^3}$$
I simply can't detect where I have gone wrong.
May someone help me ? Thank you so much.

Comment: simplifying the algebra of your last line gives $\frac{-2}{(1-x^2-y^2)^3}$. So, now the only discrepancy is the powers in the denominator: $2$ vs $3$. I haven’t fully done the computations myself so I can’t yet spot which is right.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you so much. Hope you may spare some time to do the full computations. Really appreciate it.

Comment: were there any more steps given in the first computation? particularly, did they tell you what $R(\partial_x,\partial_y)\partial_y$ is?

Comment: @peek-a-boo The above is the complete solution given in the book. They did not specify what $R(\partial_x, \partial_y) \partial_y$ means.  I guess maybe somewhere in the formula of Riemann curvature may have gone wrong , not sure. I use the formula of Riemann curvature from Wikipedia.

Comment: @peek-a-boo  Ah I see now, so maybe they mean $R^{1}_{212}$ not $R_{1212}$.  Thank you for enlightening me.

Comment: @JRmakoto As the metric is involved in the proposed solution for $R(\partial_x,\partial_y,\partial_x,\partial_y)$, every entry is covariant. This *must* correspond to low indexes.

Comment: @Didier Thank you for your comment. So does it mean it should be $R_{1212}$ ?. If that is the case, then it should power 3 at the denominator , so is a typo in the book?